# How to run fake json backend from terminal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, server

I created a fake JSON file to work as my backend, and when I initially created it, it started to run automatically. I closed it when I was done working for the day, and now I don't know how to re-open the json-server so none of the code works now.

Does anybody know how to run the json-file from the terminal after stopping it.

Answer (score 0):

Json files don't run automatically. Were you by any chance using the `json-server` npm package? If so, check those docs to find how to run it again.

Comment: Yes I was, will check it out again. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON server to do this job, install json-server module

nodejs reference module : https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server

Start JSON Server by running this command on the terminal

```
json-server --watch db.json // you give your path here
```

Now if you go to http://localhost:3000/**, you'll get

```
{ you should be able to see your object code here }
```